# Azure function app - Data automatically escaping quotes and throwing errors

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-logic-apps

I'm working with an Azure Function app that is connected to salesforce. There is a step that grabs a string of values from a field in salesforce and composes it into a value that I am sending to my on-prem service.

The problem is my List is trying to escape the quotes in the output and it's messing up my data on the back end.

The first step returns the fields as below

```
"Get_Provider_Types": {
        "inputs": {
            "host": {
                    "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['salesforce']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
        "method": "get",
        "path": "my SF connection string",
        "queries": {
            "$select": "Provider_Types__c"
        }
    },
    "runAfter": {},
    "type": "ApiConnection"
}
```

The output runs successfully and appears as below

```
[
  "Field 1",
  "Field 2",
  "Field 3"
]
```

The next step is to compose a JSON message with the values from the previous step

```
"Compose_Message": {
        "inputs": {
                "Provider_Types__c": "@{body('Get_Provider_Types')?['Provider_Types__c']}"
        },
        "runAfter": {
                "Get_Provider_Types": 
                    [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
        },
"type": "Compose"
}
```

The values from @{body('Get_Provider_Types')?['Provider_Types__c']} are returning but it appears to be trying to escape the quotes which throws an error on the back end.

```
"Provider_Types__c": "[\"Field 1\",\"Field 2\",\"Field 3\"]"
```

How can I get my data to look like the first step above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I figured out my problem pretty quickly! The {} in logic apps automatically serializes data.

I had to change

```
"@{body('Get_Provider_Types')?['Provider_Types__c']}"
```

to

```
"@body('Get_Provider_Types')?['Provider_Types__c']"
```

Only had to remove the {}. Very subtle change, hopefully this helps someone in the future.